# JavaScript Multidimensional Array - Object Linking

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I am working with javascript multidimensional array.

Here is the scenario:-

I have a educational institution where user can take classes from any subject. Subjects are not fixed it could be vary. Now there is exam day so suppose there is PHP Lang faculty who will enter his subject name then student name and then marks. If student is enrolled himself for more then 1 subject so its marks will listed in same row.

for example Mr. Anand has enrolled for PHP and HTML and Mr. Deep has enrolled himself for Php only.

Additionally I also want to show minimum and maximum marks as well.

So on result day result card will

```
Name\Subject | PHP  |  HTML   |  Java
--------------------------------------
Anand        | 80   |  60     |  --
Deep         | 70   |  --     |  --
Sachin       | 55   |  56     |  45
so on ...    | --   |  --     |  80
--------------------------------------
Min Marks    | 70   |  56     |  45
Max Mark     | 80   |  60     |  80
```

I have created a multidimensional array but unable to reproduce code as per visual. I think I am doing something wrong.

Below is the code which I have created as of now :-

```
var data = [
    ["HTML", [{
        "name": "Anand",
        "marks": 90
    }, {
        "name": "Deep",
        "marks": 79
    }, {
        "name": "Raman",
        "marks": 34
    }]],
    ["Php", [{
        "name": "Anand",
        "marks": 90
    }, {
        "name": "Ekam",
        "marks": 40
    }]]
]

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    document.write("<h2> " + data[i][0] + " </h2>");

    var secondLevelData = data[i][1],
        secondLen = secondLevelData.length;

    for (var j = 0; j < secondLen; j++) {
        document.write(secondLevelData[j].name + " -- " + secondLevelData[j].marks + " <br/>");
    }
}
```

Please help me to get the desired result. I am also working on it.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: You have created that JSON structure ?

Comment: What does the title of the question have to do with the question? I can't see any *object linking* here

Comment: @Anand so what is the question?

Comment: **vigneswaran**  I want to do it with the help of JSON and **kumar**  I want to link PHP with the people who was data related to that.

Hope my description has cleared your doubts

Comment: @Moogs  I want to create a upper define table with the help of JSON and JavaScript

Comment: Are you stuck with this object structure or can it be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing the JSON we can achieve this. Also added jQuery and underscore libraries for DOM and array manipulations

JS Fiddle Link : https://jsfiddle.net/8Lb7x01u/3/

```
var data = [
{
    "name": "Anand",
    "score": [
        {
            "subject": "HTML",
            "marks": 90
        },
        {
            "subject": "Php",
            "marks": 90
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Deep",
    "score": [
        {
            "subject": "HTML",
            "marks": 79
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Raman",
    "score": [
        {
            "subject": "HTML",
            "marks": 34
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Ekam",
    "score": [
        {
            "subject": "Php",
            "marks": 40
        }
    ]
}
];
var allScores = _.pluck(data,"score");
var allSubjects = _.groupBy(_.flatten(allScores),"subject");
var allStudents = _.pluck(data,"name");
var headerRow = $("<tr></tr>");
$("<th></th>").html("Name\\Subject").appendTo(headerRow); 
for(var subject in allSubjects){

$("<th></th>").html(subject).appendTo(headerRow);    
}
 headerRow.appendTo(".scoreCard");
for(var i=0;i<allScores.length;i++){
var individualScores = _.groupBy(allScores[i],"subject");
var tr = $("<tr></tr>");

$("<td></td>").html(allStudents[i]).appendTo(tr);
    for(var subject in allSubjects)
    {
        if(individualScores[subject]){
 $("<td></td>").html(individualScores[subject][0].marks).appendTo(tr);
        }else
        {
            $("<td></td>").html("...").appendTo(tr);
        }

}
    tr.appendTo(".scoreCard tbody")
}

renderMaxMin("max");
renderMaxMin("min");


function renderMaxMin(param){

    var footerRow = $("<tr></tr>");
    $("<td></td>").html(param+" marks").appendTo(footerRow);    
    for(var subject in allSubjects){
    var marks = _.pluck(allSubjects[subject],"marks");
    var value =(param === "max") ? _.max(marks) : _.min(marks);
    $("<td></td>").html(value).appendTo(footerRow);    
    }
    footerRow.appendTo(".scoreCard tfoot")
}
```

Comment: thank you so much @ramanathan. Can we do it with the help of jquery and javascript only?

If yes then it will be great. It may possible that code will be long but its fine.

Please suggest!!

Comment: Underscore is a very useful utility library and its also open source weighing only 6kb, so my suggestion would be to go with it. Also added the min/max marks logic https://jsfiddle.net/8Lb7x01u/3/

Comment: If you still insist in removing underscore, then the following underscore functions pluck,groupBy,flatten,min,max should be re-written, which is like reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the markup in the right manner. You should form the correct markup first, in this case it would be tables.

Also, the way you are storing data could be improved by using associative arrays. It will help you to manage it and use it better as the size of data grows. Here is how you can do that :

```
var data = [{'HTML' : 
           [{"name":"Anand","marks":90,
            {"name":"Deep","marks": 79},
            {"name":"Raman","marks": 34}]
           }],

           {'PHP' :
          [{"name":"Anand","marks": 90},
          {"name":"Ekam","marks": 40}]
          }]]
```

Comment: I can modify JSON to get the desired result. Please suggest!!